# Event for resize stopped

Tags: jquery

Is there an event that tells me when the user has stopped resizing by letting go of the mouse button?  I'm looking at $(window).resize, and it's firing for every pixel movement.  I just need to know when they've stopped.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, but you can defer the event handler if you want:

```
function onResize(){ ... }

var timer;

$(window).bind('resize', function(){
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }

    timer = setTimeout(onResize, 100);
});
```

This will make it fire 100ms after the user has stopped resizing.

Comment: @Spooky -- I _strongly_ object to needless edits on other people's answers.

Comment: @zyklus Read the edit summary I included. The `timer && clearTimeout(timer);` is _needlessly_ obfuscated, which does not assist with the understanding of your code, especially for those who are newer to JavaScript. Can you please explain _why_ you think that this is not the case?

Comment: @Spooky -- Because this is a common pattern and it's not your place to attempt to _force your own opinion of what is and is not needless_ on other people's answers.

Comment: @zyklus The edit itself was a _suggested_ edit, which I didn't force. The only purpose of using such a pattern is to reduce the number of characters. That's the only _need_ for it, which is why it is _needless_ to write such code anywhere other than [codegolf.stackexchange.com](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com). I see my suggested edit as objectively improving the clarity of the line of code in question. Do you honestly think otherwise?

Comment: I see your edits as needless as they are _preferential_ and don't add anything.  The `a && b` pattern is _perfectly_ clear to me and many other people.  Although I'll admit that people brand new to the language might not understand it, I don't believe in dumbing down code to the lowest common denominator (if we did that there wouldn't be any code at all!).  You could argue that `a = b ? c : d` should be re-written to `if( b ){ a = c; } else { a = d; }`, or you could argue that you want there to be more whitespace, etc.  However, these are all _preferences_ and add nothing.

Comment: It may be clear to you and "many other people" but it's not to me. What does line mean? `timer && clearTimeout(timer);`?

Comment: @TetraDev -- `if(timer) { clearTimeout(timer); }`; the `&&` op is frequently used for this purpose, though I admit it's confusing the first time you see it

Comment: @zyklus I upvoted your answer because of your clarification in a comment. But I agree with Spooky and TetraDev, that the code is a bit confusing and difficult to read. Besides, the if statement is not necessary in this case. The line can be rewritten as `clearTimeout(timer);` and it still works perfectly.

Comment: @Webars - True, but it's an anti-pattern.  The problem is that though it works here if you encourage the pattern of relying on the function to handle null data you quickly run into situations that do cause errors.  Now you're left memorizing which functions handle null/undefined and which don't and having different coding patterns for different function calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
function rsizeItems() 
{ }

var tOut = false;
var milSec = 500;
$(window).resize(function(){
 if(tOut !== false)
    clearTimeout(tOut);
 tOut = setTimeout(rsizeItems, milSec);
});
```

Comment: Oh, I'm glad you indented your code. I almost got caught by the missing { in your if stmt.  #stillanoob